# How do I gain access to Octopus' database post-installation?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, octopus-deploy

I have an Octopus server setup using defaults in most configuraiton options; for example, it runs under the `LOCAL SYSTEM` account, and has created its own database on the local SQL server instance.

For reasons related to the deployment process of one of our projects, I need to switch the account under which the Octopus service runs, but when I do, it looses access to the database. When I try to use the own account to add the required permissions, I too am denied access.

The only two logins defined on the server are `BUILTIN\Users` and `sa`; I've made my domain account a member of the former group, but that's apparently not enough, and I don't have the password to `sa`.

Is there any way I can gain access to this database without completely re-installing Octopus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As administrator on the local machine, you will be administrator on the SQL Server installation. *But* you will need to start Management Studio with "Run as administrator".